# SQL date selection as NULL, After, Before, Between

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Requirement: select by date as After, Before, Between or all if null

I'm using SQL Server 2008

This is my attempt but I'm getting syntax errors on code that is valid used outside of the case.

1. Is there a better method?
2. using case what is the correct syntax?

   ```
   declare @StartDate datetime;    
   declare @EndDate datetime;
   SET @EndDate = GETDATE();
   SET @StartDate = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()); 

   select *
   from ArCustomer
   where CAST(Customer as int) > 1000
   AND
       CASE WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN
           ArCustomer.DateLastSale BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
       WHEN @StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL THEN
           ArCustomer.DateLastSale < @EndDate 
       WHEN @StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NULL THEN
           ArCustomer.DateLastSale > @StartDate        
   END;
   ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternately, you could not restrict by the date parameter if it is `NULL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM ArCustomer ac
WHERE 
    CAST(ac.Customer as int) > 1000
    AND (ac.DateLastSale >= @StartDate OR @StartDate IS NULL)
    AND (ac.DateLastSale <= @EndDate OR @EndDate IS NULL)
```

Or... you can handle the `NULL` by treating it as the low-end or high-end date:

```
SELECT *
FROM ArCustomer ac
WHERE 
    CAST(ac.Customer as int) > 1000
    AND ac.DateLastSale BETWEEN ISNULL(@StartDate, '1900-01-01') 
        AND ISNULL(@EndDate, '9999-12-31')
```

---

**EDIT:**

There could be a difference in the execution plan between these two approaches, so you might try both methods and see if one out-performs the other...

Comment: thanks, looks like that did it (option 1) and is much more elegant than my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CAST(Customer as int) > 1000 AND
     (@StartDate IS NULL OR @StartDate <= ArCustomer.DateLastSale) AND
     (@EndDate IS NULL OR ArCustomer.DateLastSale <= @EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please note that the below query should have * avoided and the specific column names should be mentioned.**

```
declare @StartDate datetime;    
declare @EndDate datetime;
SET @EndDate = GETDATE();
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()); 

Declare @SQL Varchar(1000)

Set @SQL = 'select ColumnName
from ArCustomer
where CAST(Customer as int) > 1000
AND'
if(@StartDate IS NOT NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL)
Begin
    Set @SQL = @SQL + ' ArCustomer.DateLastSale BETWEEN ''' + Convert(varchar, @StartDate) + 
    ''' AND ''' + Convert(varchar, @EndDate) + ''''
End
else if(@StartDate IS NULL AND @EndDate IS NOT NULL)
Begin   
        Set @SQL = @SQL + ' ArCustomer.DateLastSale < ''' + Convert(varchar, @EndDate) + ''''
End
else
    Set @SQL = @SQL + ' ArCustomer.DateLastSale > ''' + Convert(varchar, @StartDate) + ''''        


exec(@SQL)
```

Considered all cases.